# Android Google Sign-in with Firebase Authentication signs in unreliably

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Good day

I am currently working on an app requiring google sign-in. I followed the instructions provided by firebase available here:https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

However, I am receiving unreliable sign in from the app. It was working well for a while and then started giving problems. Unfortunately, there isn't even much of a trend for me to describe. It mostly happens when on mobile data but sometimes, even on wifi. Sometimes it signs in and sometimes it doesn't. Along with this, sometimes it throws a FirebaseNetworkError and sometimes it simply doesn't do anything. I should probably mention that I have double checked that there is always a reliable internet connection when it fails (I always checked a Youtube video and looked up a few pages on Chrome). I also tested on about 10 different android devices on different mobile and wifi networks. Essentially, sometimes it signs in, sometimes it doesn't.

I have done a large amount of research but haven't found anything. If I've missed something, please do let me know.

**EDIT:** Once the user has been signed in there is no problem. All the other firebase services work perfectly.

Here is my Authentication Activity (I have a separate Authentication that then launches into my Main):

```
public class Authentication extends AppCompatActivity implements 
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

  private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
  private GoogleApiClient apiClient;
  private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
  SignInButton button;
  Button signOut;
  private static final String TAG = "GoogleActivity";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.hide();


    button = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.googleSignIN);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signIn();

        }


    });

    signOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSignOut);
    signOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signOut();
        }
    });


    // Set up Google Sign-in options
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    // Set up Sign-In Api Client
    apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();


    //mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if current user is signed in
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    startMain(currentUser);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthGoogle(account);
        } else {

            startMain(null);

        }
    }
}

private void firebaseAuthGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {


    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);

    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                startMain(user);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, task.getException());
                Toast.makeText(Authentication.this, "Authentication Failed. Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startMain(null);
            }

        }
    });
}

private void signIn() {

    Intent signIn = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(apiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signIn, RC_SIGN_IN);

}

private void signOut() {
    mFirebaseAuth.signOut();

    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(apiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            startMain(null);
        }

    });
}

private void revokeAccess() {

    mFirebaseAuth.signOut();

    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(apiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            startMain(null);
        }
    });
}

private void startMain(FirebaseUser currentUser) {
    if (currentUser != null) {

        Intent i = new Intent(Authentication.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(Authentication.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Here is a stack trace for a network error:

```
07-01 15:28:19.991 30844-30844/***.*********.******** W/GoogleActivity: 
com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as 
timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.jz.zzK(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.jb.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.kj.zzL(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.kl.onFailure(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
com.google.android.gms.internal.kb.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                       at 
android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Manifest Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Project gradle dependancies:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
```

Module gradle dependancies (relevant ones):

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-base:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
```

I also do have Google sign-in enabled in my firebase console, I have entered my SHA-1 key, downloaded the google-service.json file from firebase again and generated a signed-apk and tested it.

I am quite frustrated at this point in time because sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't so any suggestions are welcome and much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the problem. Here are suggestions for anyone who may be facing the same problem:

1. In the android monitor there is a handy option to select only 'firebase' logs (excuse my naivity, I didn't know this). In my case it revealed that the there was no network connection. However, this was due to the fact that Google Services was restricted on Mobile Data on my device.
2. The problem persisted on other devices as well, though, so I generated a release SHA-1 key as well and added that to my firebase project. I downloaded a new google-services.json file and added it (whether this was necessary I don't know, it was just a precaution). I had tested signed apks on some of my other devices when I couldn't figure anything else out. Therefore, I think that this solved the login problem on the other devices.